# Programmatically add a Rule to the Web.Config (system.webServer.rewrite.rules).rule name="IP Blocking" Node

Tags: c#, web

I am using UrlRewrite Rules to block Bots and Trolls.

Currently its a Manual Task to add the entry, either via IIS or editing the Web.config file.

I want to add a Rule to the: (system.webServer.rewrite.rules).rule name="IP Blocking" Node if I get High Volume Traffic which I monitor via a WinForms App reading the IIS Log Files.

A Web.config entry might look like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="IP Blocking" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="0.0.0.0" />
          <add input="{HTTP_X_Forwarded_For}" pattern="0.0.0.0" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I started looking into the 'ConfigurationManager' to edit and save the Web.config:

```
ConfigurationManager config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = path }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationSection WebServer = config.GetSection("system.webServer");
```

or:

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(path);
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

There appears to be no way to access/edit: 'system.webServer' in the config.

My Goal is to have the Web.config edited and saved Programmatically.

Comment: have you tried using [webconfigurationmanager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but any changes to the web.config will force (and in fact, require) a recompile to the site.

If you're going to block ip addresses, why don't you do it on the firewall instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is just endless issues with the approach!

- ConfigurationManager
- WebConfigurationManager

Everyone has reported issues with it!

I ended up going with simple XML Approach:

```
// Instantiate XmlDocument:
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

// Load XML from the Web.config file:
doc.Load("Config/Web.config");

// Get the Rules Nodes:
XmlNodeList Rules = doc.SelectNodes("/configuration/system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule");

// Loop through the Rules:
foreach (XmlNode Rule in Rules)
{

// Get the Name:
XmlAttribute NodeName = Rule.Attributes["name"];

// Check we have the correct Node:
if (NodeName.Value == "IP Blocking")
{

// Grab the Conditions Node:
XmlNode Conditions = Rule.SelectNodes("conditions").Item(0);
Conditions = Rule.SelectNodes("conditions").Item(0);

// Create the 'REMOTE_ADDR' Element:
XmlElement Element = doc.CreateElement("add");
Element.SetAttribute("input", "{REMOTE_ADDR}");
Element.SetAttribute("pattern", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");

// Append the Element to the 'Conditions' Node:
Conditions.AppendChild(Element);

// Create the 'HTTP_X_Forwarded_For' Element:
Element = doc.CreateElement("add");
Element.SetAttribute("input", "{HTTP_X_Forwarded_For}");
Element.SetAttribute("pattern", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");

// Append the Element to the 'Conditions' Node:
Conditions.AppendChild(Element);
}
}

// Save to Disk:
doc.Save(...
```

Seems .Net is starting to become a little neglected by MS and co!

Of course the above code gives me:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="IP Blocking" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" />
                <add input="{HTTP_X_Forwarded_For}" pattern="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```